# Aptana 3 Github Clone Repository Fail

Tags: git, github, aptana

I`m having a problem with cloning github repository using Aptana Studio 3.
I selected Fil -> Import -> Git Repository.
I have a repo at https://github.com/justmyfreak/PHP-RSS. I tried to add uri by using the url https://github.com/justmyfreak/PHP-RSS but it said that Failed to import via git clone.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `git://github.com/justmyfreak/PHP-RSS.git` or `https://github.com/justmyfreak/PHP-RSS.git`. I think you just forgot the `.git`

Comment: Get the same issue but than @justmyfreak but the adress is well written. The error is error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version. The repository is well created and functional (work for other people)

Comment: No, you should ask a new question.