# Aptana Studio error with Git

Tags: github, aptana, aptana3

I get the same issue than in [Aptana 3 Github Clone Repository Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439698/aptana-3-github-clone-repository-fail/7439837?noredirect=1#comment85998953_7439837) but the adress is well written. The error is

> error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version.

The repository is well created and functional (work for other people)

Could someone please help me ?